# Insertion sort algorithm runtime

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to see the difference in runtime for different sorting algorithms when I found that I was getting consistently faster runtime for one version of Insertion sort than another version of insertion sort. The versions of the algorithms seem nearly Identical (only a 1 off the difference). I am not sure why. One version (slower one) is from w3resource and the other one (faster one) is from geeksforgeeks. I am doing the comparison in python.

Geeks for Geeks

```
def insertion_sort_geeks(a):
    """
    https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/
    :param a: Array
    :return:  time to sort
    """
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        current_val = a[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and a[j] > current_val:
            a[j + 1] = a[j]
            j -= 1
        a[j + 1] = current_val
    end = time.time()
    return end - start
```

W3Resource Algorithm

```
def insertion_sort_w3(a):
    """
    https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/data-structures-and-algorithms/python-search-and-sorting-exercise-6.php
    :param a: array
    :return: time to sort
    """
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        current_val = a[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and a[j - 1] > current_val:
            a[j] = a[j - 1]
            j -= 1
        a[j] = current_val
    end = time.time()
    return end - start
```

When I run these algorithms, I consistently find that the geeksforgeeks algorithm is faster but cannot figure out why?

-- Sort on a list of 10,000 ints (randomized)

```
Insertion Sort Geek     Insertion Sort W3
4.727362155914307       5.441751718521118
4.595118761062622       5.537100791931152
4.742804050445557       5.453729867935181
4.684415102005005       5.44006609916687
4.790072202682495       5.50256085395813
4.789106845855713       5.894493818283081
5.104598045349121       6.107465982437134
5.100121021270752       5.738892078399658
4.825102090835571       5.55505895614624
4.877285003662109       5.7944769859313965
```

https://github.com/ShamsAnsari/Algorithms

https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/data-structures-and-algorithms/python-search-and-sorting-exercise-6.php
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top one defines j once per outer loop. 10.000 times. In the bottom one you have to decrease j in every inner loop control for testing. That's (10.000 * 10.000 - 10.000)/2 as an upper limit (thanks to @trincot for correcting this) operations more.

Slower Version:

```
j = i
       while j > 0 and a[j - 1] > current_val:
```

Faster Version:

```
j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and a[j] > current_val:
```

I think the a[j - 1] is the  main difference.

Comment: I decrease j in both Algorithms (inside while statement)

Comment: Yes, the body of the loop is pretty much the same, the control part is not. I edited my post for clarification @ShamsAnsari

Comment: This is the right answer. However, *"That's 10.0000 * 10.000 - 10.000"* should be *"That's up to (10.000 * 10.000 - 10.000) / 2"* (one zero removed, division added, and it's an upper limit)

Comment: I added a counter inside the while loop for both algorithms and both while loops execute the same number of times @vaegn

Comment: That's how it should be. The difference is, that you do the "j - 1" outside of the loop or in the loop control. If you do it in the loop control it is calculated for the numbers the loop body is run + 1 for the final check that would not enter the loop body. 

When you calculate the j-1 before you enter the loop control, you save that tiny calculation time.